# printf in main function returning twice in C

Tags: c

I am running such a weird problem in C. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
                                                                        
#define NUM_OF_CORES 1
#define MAX_PRIME 100000
                                                                        
unsigned long do_primes()
{
    unsigned long i, num, primes = 0;
    for (num = 1; num <= MAX_PRIME; ++num) {
        for (i = 2; (i <= num) && (num % i != 0); ++i);
        if (i == num)
            ++primes;
    }
    //printf("Calculated %ld primes.\n", primes);
    return primes;
}
                                                                        
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    //printf ("TEST <CPUBURN_PRIME TEST>\n");
    time_t start, end;
    time_t run_time;
    int i;
    static unsigned long prime_count = 0;
    pid_t pids[NUM_OF_CORES];
                                                                        
    /* start of test */
    start = time(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CORES; i++) {
        if (!(pids[i] = fork())) {
            prime_count = do_primes();
            printf("Calculated %ld primes.\n", prime_count);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (pids[i] < 0) {
            perror("Fork");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CORES; ++i) {
        waitpid(pids[i], NULL, 0);
    }
    end = time(NULL);
    run_time = (end - start);
    
    printf("<TEST:CPUBURN_PRIME TEST><%d--%ld--%ld>\n", MAX_PRIME, prime_count, run_time);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

**Calculated 9592 primes.
<TEST:CPUBURN_PRIME TEST><100000--0--3>**

The problem is the last printf is returing twice. Therefore I am loosing the value of the variable prime_count. What wrong that I am doing?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last printf is returing twice"? Please copy-paste the *exact*, *full* and *complete* output of the program into your question.

Comment: Or perhaps maybe the problem is that `prime_count` is only set in the *child* processes, and is not communicated back to the parent process? Then haven't your tutorials or books about processes told you that processes are separate, without any sharing? Perhaps what you really want is *threads*?

Comment: <TEST:CPUBURN_PRIME TEST><100000--9473--3><TEST:CPUBURN_PRIME TEST><100000--0--3> These are two lines that I always get. Its not about the child process. I have assigned the value in the main function. That might be about thread. Because, first, it prints the correct value, next time when it returns 0, it prints the value 0. So basically the printf is calling after quitting the thread.

Comment: Have you run this code yet? If you, then you will possibly know what I am am talking about. My point is how prime_count variable could be zero, where I can see the value inside of the loop. I debugged through this, then find out that printf is calling twice, probably after quiting the main function. Thats why its getting the value for prime_count 0

Comment: The only way that output can happen is if both the parent and child process runs and executes that specific `printf` call. Which means the `exit(0)` call in the shown code never happens. And that can only happen if the code you run doesn't actually have that `exit(0)` call. So the code you show isn't the code you run.

Comment: As a simple way to trace and debug this problem is to include the process id in all output you make,. And to make much more tracing/debugging output (like printing the result of `fork()`).

Comment: And *please* take some time to refresh the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). The questions should be complete, with all expected and actual output. Lastly please don't forget how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prime_count` would not be updated since it's not changed in the parent process. Only the `fork`-d child process updates its own copy of `prime_count`. You would need to establish some form of Inter-Process communication between the two processes so that the parent can read back the value of `prime_count` from the child. One of the (many) ways could be to use [`pipes`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) as follows (this is ***not production level code***)

```
if (!(pids[i] = fork())) {
    close(pipes[i][0]);
    prime_count = do_primes();
    printf("%d Calculated %ld primes.\n",getpid(), prime_count);
    char buff[100] = {0};
    sprintf(buff, "%ld", prime_count);
    write(pipes[i][1], buff, strlen(buff));
    close(pipes[i][1]);
    exit(0);
} else if(pids[i] > 0) {
    close(pipes[i][1]);
    char buff[100];
    read(pipes[i][0], buff, sizeof(buff));
    printf("Read num primes %s\n", buff);
    prime_count = strtol(buff, NULL, 10);
    close(pipes[i][0]);
} else {
    perror("Fork");
    exit(1);
}
```

This is just an example and might suffice when `NUM_CORES` is 1. You'll need to adapt it to read asynchronously from the pipe since `read` is a blocking call by default and the parent process won't get to proceed with the subsequent loop iterations in case the read is blocked.